# Retrieving data from ArcGIS webmap

Tags: arcgis-online-webmap, peru

The Peruvian government created a [webmap](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https://services3.arcgis.com/KOykOZqSeI64Fz9Y/ArcGIS/rest/services/PUNTOS_COVID_gdb/FeatureServer/0&source=sd) where you can find all COVID test centers in Lima. It's public data and I would like to know if there is some legal way to download the points shown on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Services available here
https://services3.arcgis.com/KOykOZqSeI64Fz9Y/ArcGIS/rest/services/PUNTOS_COVID_gdb/FeatureServer/0

Example to get all data in GeoJSON format:

`https://services3.arcgis.com/KOykOZqSeI64Fz9Y/ArcGIS/rest/services/PUNTOS_COVID_gdb/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token=`

Sample output:

```
> {   "type" : "FeatureCollection",    "features" : [
>     {
>       "type" : "Feature", 
>       "geometry" : 
>       {
>         "type" : "Point", 
>         "coordinates" : [
>           -77.0224199, -12.1445770999999
>         ]
>       }, 
>       "properties" : null
>     }, 
>     {
>       "type" : "Feature", 
>       "geometry" : 
>       {
>         "type" : "Point", 
>         "coordinates" : [
>           -77.0204924, -12.1504676
>         ]
>       }, 
>       "properties" : null
>     }, 
>     {
>       "type" : "Feature", 
>       "geometry" : 
>       {
>         "type" : "Point", 
>         "coordinates" : [
>           -77.0048743999999, -12.1887664
>         ]
>       }, 
>       "properties" : null
>     },
```

parse with geojson 2.5.0
https://pypi.org/project/geojson/

Comment: thank you very much! :) this work great